# Selenium Python - working with dynamic iframe popups

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I will try to explain this best i can. I am trying to automatically enter data onto a web page. This is the basic representation of it:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <body>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="'header"></div>
                <div id="content"></div>
                <div id="footer"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="control_window_11" class="simple_window" style="margin: 0px; position: absolute; z-index: 10008; display: none;"><div class="modalReportWindowClose"></div></div>
            <iframe undefined="position:absolute;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0);display:none" src="javascript:void(0);" frameborder="0" style="position: absolute; display: none;"></iframe>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

```
`<div id="control_window_10"></div> and <iframe></iframe>`
```

are both generated dynamically when i click save. After saving, the popup will go away and `<div id="control_window_10"` will be changed too: `<div id="control_window_11"`.
the issue appears after the first successful iteration of the program. When it clicks 'save' and id=control_window changes from 10 to 11 (keep in mind it will increase every iteration contril_window_12, 13, 14 and so on.). although every single iframe and div are generated the same, selenium will still be looking at control_window_10 and not be able to find elements. i have tried to index them by Xpath, id, class, ive even tried to dynamically change the numbers myself.

Comment: It's unclear where you are typing the info here... is it in the iframe?  If so, just use a locator that targets that.  To target the div, just find what's unique... if it's the only DIV with id="control_window..." then use something like XPATH of //div[contains(@id, 'control_window')]

Comment: The issue is just trying to locate the new window or frame. every time i click the save button, a new iframe is created for the updated page, but selenium still thinks its controlling the old frame. Switching frames does not work either

Comment: once the frame has been removed from the DOM, your driver will be in nomansland.  Be sure to switch back to the parent using driver.switchTo(). defaultContent(), or by switching directly to the new frame.  You should probably also use a webdriverwait with expected condition of frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(int)  You should probably also add some code trials to your post here.